# Javascript code not working in LINUX Weblogic, works fine in UNIX box

Tags: javascript, linux, migration, weblogic

I have a unique issue where the Java script code that works in UNIX(Weblogic 10.3.2) is not working after migrating to LINUX (Weblogic 12.2)

The code changes when we check the code using view source

```
function checkAll(field)
    {
    alert(field.rowKeyVar);
    for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++){
        field[i].checked = true ;
        }
    }
```

changes to

```
function checkAll(field)
        {
        alert(field.rowKeyVar);
        for (i = 0; i &lt; field.length; i++){
            field[i].checked = true ;
            }
        }
```

The error when we click on the button to invoke the javascript function is :

> SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control

Any pointers on this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear what process is in place to convert/migrate your code, but it appears that it’s converted your `<` to `&lt;`. So now your for-loop has a third semicolon before reaching the closing paren. So the error makes sense, and you need to fix your migration process to not html-escape your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well lucky me I was wable to resolve it pretty soon.
I removed the JS code from the XHTML file and moved the whole JS code to a new JS file. I included the JS file in the head of the XHTML file and that resolved the issue as by doing this I was able to escape the conversion hence resolving the problem.